# Cross-moderation between Video and Sound undone - Video still needs 1 more mod!

Tags: discussion, moderation

While the split was going on, it made perfect sense for moderators on Video and Sound Design to be moderators on both places - this allowed everyone to move questions around easily, as needed.

Now that migrations are all but complete (about a dozen potentially remain), it's no longer necessary to have cross moderation in place.

***If you were a moderator on AVP, you're now a moderator on Sound Design***

As the moderators here were *mostly* on the sound side of things, they've carried their appointments over to Sound Design. They did a fantastic job while here, and are continuing to do a fantastic job on Sound Design. I'm certain you'll see them drop in from time to time, but they'll be ordinary users on this (refocused) Video site.

***Video Needs One Additional Moderator***

[AJ And Rory graciously accepted nomination](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/who-should-the-new-moderators-be) to become (or remain) a moderator here on Video, but we need a third moderator to complete the team. Normally, at this point, I'd be going through the ranks of users and identifying likely candidates that consistently demonstrate the kinds of qualities we'd hope to find in moderators.

Due to the split, some users that fit this criteria quite well are mostly active on *Sound Design* now, so it's going to be a couple of weeks before things normalize to the point that identifying someone on my own will be feasible again.

We're fine, for now, but I'd like to get a third moderator appointed much sooner than later. If you think you'd like to join the team, or know of a user that would be a great fit and might be interested, head over to the nomination post and let us know!

A big thank you to *everyone* that helped this project go smoothly - we couldn't have done this as well as we did without you.